# Add string to bean

Tags: java, vaadin, javabeans

Right now I'm using a java bean, which contains 5 strings, to display information on a grid in vaadin. Now, I'm going to have to change this to be able to hold 7 strings, but I was wondering: is there a way to just add 2 strings to the java bean I already have?

Comment: Any code to go with that question, or do we have to guess how it is currently built? Are you using a `List<String>` or do you have 5 different properties that are `String` objects?

Comment: You add them the same way you added the other 5 strings.

Comment: I have 5 different properties which are all strings. An arrayList doesn't allow me to edit items in the vaadin grid, and the string array doesn't display the strings I want to edit in the grid

Comment: The problem is that I also have to display only 5 strings at times, and I may have to display more than 5 at others. I was wondering if I could find a way to avoid creating an entirely new bean

Comment: Which container do you use for Grid? BeanItemContainer?

Comment: I'm using a beanItemContainer for the grid

Answer (score 0):

Reading the your comments I guess you could just make your bean contain all 7 strings. When you do not need to show all these properties as columns in the Grid then just [remove](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.columns.removing) unnecessary ones. E.g. use [removeColumn](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#removeColumn%28java.lang.Object%29).